# Composer missing libraries in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php, composer-php, ubuntu-18.04

I have installed composer but when I try to run `$ composer` I get the following error:

> php: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.55: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file or directory

The `php -v` command returns:

> PHP 7.1.23-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Oct 15 2018
>   11:37:26) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group Zend Engine
>   v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.1.23-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

I have tried to search for `libicu` in synaptic and I installed libicu60!

However, `php composer.phar` works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

composer shouldn't need that dependency, but in case it really does, this should work:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu55_55.1-7_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libicu55_55.1-7_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```

However, I'd post that as a bug to composer maintainers (github repo), because the package should have this as a dependency and install it along the way with apt.

Composer.phar is really a standalone program, so it doesn't need other dependencies. much like a snap package.

Comment: Composer is not standalone program. It requires PHP and some PHP extensions to run. And in some cases other programs (like git) too. It is pretty far from snap package.

Comment: After applying the solution you regarded, another similar issue raised with another library `libmysqlclient.so.20` I think that it is more than missing one library, I think that it is an issue in php-cli installation itself. I have no idea to solve it!

Comment: seems like your application wants to use something you have not yet installed (like php7.1-mysql)

Comment: PHP works fine in the apache server and in the command line. Like you have suggested, I opened [**this issue**](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/7730) on the composer's repo.

Comment: then my answer helped for the original question :) Feel free to mark it solved. I'll try to help our in the composer github issue, too.